# Wpf: Alternative to xaml.cs file containing only deafult constructor and InitializeComponent() call

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I use MVVM.
Is there any convenient way not to have xaml.cs files but somehow still calling InitializeComponent()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this out:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.TestBrowser"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Initialize Component Test"
        Height="300"
        Width="300">
    <StackPanel>
        <ListBox x:Name="lb"/>
        <x:Code>
            <![CDATA[
public TestBrowser()
{
  InitializeComponent();
  lb.ItemsSource = new[] { "Hey" };
}
]]>
        </x:Code>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

When such a XAML file is compiled, the contents inside the [x:Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970568.aspx#x_Code) element get plopped
inside the partial class in the .g.cs file.

I still would not recommend this practice. As for me it makes code less readable, and I'm not sure whether Blend or Kaxaml understands it.

Comment: I like it but maybe something more declarative would be better. Perhaps a custom tag?

Comment: Really doubt it is possible. InitializeComponent() loads XAML, and only then it's processed. Alternatives may include loading XAML resources manually, somewhere in Application, but it's a headache.

Comment: It contradicts the example above. Or you mean except <![CDATA[ .. ]]> ?

Comment: I would accept your answer if you could at least semi-proof that no better solution exists.

Comment: Naeron, the latest comment doesn't contradict the example. x:Code is processed by XAML compiler and it's not interpreted in runtime...